# draw multiple rectangles without fps drop with framegraphics

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to draw some rectangles on my panel and then make them fall down but because of my program needs to redraw the background and every rectangle everytime it loops the fps is dropping alot when I add alot of rectangles.

this is my code to draw all the rectangles:

```
frameGraphics.FillRectangles(Red, rectlist.ToArray());
```

Is there anyother way to make this faster? since the rectlist.toarray() contains around 400-500 rectangles.

---

I'm using winforms:

```
        Graphics g = Canvas.CreateGraphics(); where canvas is my panel.
        Bitmap frame = new Bitmap(Game.CANVAS_WIDTH, Game.CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        Graphics frameGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(frame);
```

this is how I build up my graphics.

Comment: I think you can indicate what platform are you using, Winform, wpf, web or pure console?

Comment: Gdi+ is a poor choice for making games. This is mainly about concepts: scene, sprites, light, input, sounds, etc. I haven't made any game yet, but if I have to, then I'd go for `xna`-like. `ToArray` takes very little compared to that, what is needed to draw even single rectangle. You can not increase fps, unless you will start using algorithm optimizations (3d buffer to example), which are again already implemented in game frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Winform is using Gdi+ which lockes a lot during its real drawing. So it limits the drawing speed. I think there are several options for you.

1. Use XNA + Winform. You can check this article for detial. This gives little enhancements.
   http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/338422-xna-and-winforms/
   https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/54998/winform-xna-microsoft-example-issues-with-drawing-texture2d
2. Try other toolkits like SlimX or Direct3D which will be faster than Gdi+.
3. Strongly recommend you to use Wpf, you can create shapes and dynamically change their positions, so that you don't need to take care of the render part.